# How to resolve Java.lang.ThreadLocal.get() is null when trying to run Parallel plus Sequential execution in testng.xml?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, parallel-processing, nullpointerexception, testng

```
In testng.xml, I am running few tests paralleled(parallel="classes" thread-count="5") and few sequentially as two different tests. But for first testmethod from second test it is throwing NullPointerException because value of Java.lang.ThreadLocal.get() is null. I am calling setDriver() from InvokedMethodListener.beforeInvocation() and removeDriver() from InvokedMethodListener.afterInvocation().

`public class DriverFactory {
 private static DriverFactory instance = new DriverFactory();

 public static synchronized DriverFactory getInstance() {
    return instance;
 }

 ThreadLocal<WebDriver> tlDriver = new ThreadLocal<>();

 public synchronized void setDriver(String browserName) {
    if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.args", "--disable-logging");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        tlDriver.set(new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions));

    } else if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
         System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") +
         "/Drivers/geckodriver.exe");
        FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
        FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
        firefoxOptions.setHeadless(true).setProfile(firefoxProfile);
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.args", "--disable-logging");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.silentOutput", "true");
        tlDriver.set(new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions));
    } 
 public synchronized void removeDriver() {
    try {
    tlDriver.get().quit();
    tlDriver.remove();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("***AfterRemove***");
        System.out.println(e);
        //System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
   }
   }

 `
```

I have tried changing the sequence of tests but no use.Problem might be with webdriver instance from thread pool is seting up properly.Sometimes it is also throwing exception a org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException:Error communicatimg with remote browser.It may have died.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Driver server process died prematurely.   Getting above message in console.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are trying to run should be (suite > test > classes > class >methods) in the testng xml and also mention the Listener (suite > listeners > listener) class in testng xml